# How many pneumatic actuators does one air tank support

Tags: technic, pneumatic

For example, I want to use air tanks to supply pressure to up to 18 pneumatic actuators (19475c01), but I don't know how many air tanks I should buy to supply the air pressure required by all of them. Does it have something to do with load? I suppose that I don't have too much load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An air tank (at least LEGO low capacity ones) are not meant to directly supply actuators. Their main purpose is to smooth out the pressure of air flow produced by a pump (manual or motorized).